# Getting the value of a field when the ID uses dot.notation

Tags: jquery, forms

Check my edits for more detail:

I've done a lot of messing around with this to no avail. Time to turn to the experts...

The IDs on my form elements are using dot.notation (and there's nothing I can do about it). Given that caveat, the following works perfectly:

```
$("input[id='primaryEmail.Revisit']").blur(function() {
        var emailValue = $(this).val();
        alert(emailValue);
});
```

However, the following does not:

```
function getEmailVal() {
        var emailValue = $("input[id='primaryEmail.Revisit']").val();
        return emailValue;  
}
$("#login").click(function() {
        var emailValue = getEmailVal();
        alert(emailValue);
        rebakeCookies();
});
```

I've also tried these:

```
function getEmailVal() {
        var emailValue = $("input[id='primaryEmail.Revisit']").attr("value");
        return emailValue;  
}

function getEmailVal() {
        var emailValue = $("#primaryEmail\\.Revisit").val();
        return emailValue;  
}
```

First, how do I get the value using the function, and second, why can I use val() with the blur function and not with my function?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

I've resolved it - at least for my purposes. But I'm still not sure what the answer to the original question is? To solve this I added a class to the input field and referenced that selector instead - this works just fine:

```
function getEmailVal() {
        var emailValue = $(".primaryEmailRevisit").val();
        return emailValue;  
    }

$("#login").click(function() {
        var emailValue = getEmailVal();
        alert(emailValue);
        rebakeCookies();
    });
```

Comment: Are the functions actually called? Add `console.log` or `alert` to debug.

Comment: if an id is set in the input you don't need the input part in your call at all.  Change `$("input[id='primaryEmail.Revisit']")` to `$("#primaryEmail.Revisit")`.  Not sure if that will fix anything

Comment: You've shown that your selector works. This means that you're not getting the value you expect. To know why, we'd need to know how/when `getEmailVal` is being called.

Comment: @Henesnarfel: That would more likely break it. If the `.` isn't part of an attribute value in quotes, then the `.` would need to be escaped.

Comment: Sorry, I took the alert out of the function before I pasted it here. The alert that WAS in the function was returning nothing.

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor: How and when are you calling the function? And is this the *actual* code you're testing?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is voted down twice? I think it's a valid question. I realize I forgot to show you that I'm calling the function, but I assumed it was a given. The blur function reads the value of the field. My function does not and I'm referencing the field the same way the blur function does. Seems like a valid question.

Comment: It is downvoted twice because the question is incomplete. We don't know under what circumstances the function is being called. You've been asked for more information, but haven't given it. If you don't provide more info, the question can't be answered (without random guessing), and should really just be closed.

Comment: Have you considered trying real JavaScript? `document.getElementById('primaryEmail.Revisit');` works perfectly fine. If you must, you can then pass that to jQuery: `$(document.getElementById('primaryEmail.Revisit'));`

Comment: I'm sure this will work, and I will give it a try. But really it doesn't answer the question I'm asking - why does the blur function return the value when MY function does not. I'm calling it the same way.

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor: [The code you provided works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/4csqL/) Whatever the issue is, it's been excluded from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using calling the function after the document is ready? Blur never going to be called before document ready, so it would make sense that blur would work, but your function wouldn't if you were calling the function before the element is rendered.

Below is a sample of calling your function. I'd strongly suggest that format of selector, as it's more common notation.

html:

```
<input id="primaryEmail.Revisit" value="this.works@hotgmail.comnet" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

js:

```
var getEmailVal = function(){
    return $('input#primaryEmail\\.Revisit').val();
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result").html(getEmailVal());
});
```

Comment: The issue isn't with the selector. The same selector is used to assign the `blur` handler, and that one works fine.

Comment: I think you need to look at the question again. OP stated that the first code example works. Your answer doesn't do anything to solve the issue (partly because the question is incomplete).

Comment: Ah, you're right. Edited again. The code sample now demonstrates calling his function. More than likely it's not being called after document ready.

Comment: I'd say your updated answer is mostly likely the issue. Can't know for certain without more info.

Comment: I'm calling the getEmailVal function from a click function. These are all within document ready.

Answer (score -3):

It should work fine even to get the value. Take a look at this fiddle it works fine. May be there is some other issue in your code.

```
$(function(){
    $("input[id='id.id']").blur(function(){
        alert($("input[id='id.id']").val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E4mz9/268/

Comment: The `.` doesn't need to be escaped when it is part of a quoted attribute value. The first example in the question demonstrates that the selector does work.

Comment: I think you may need to take a closer look at the question. The code in the `blur` handler was working fine. The code in the `getEmailVal` doesn't work, even though it uses the same selector to assign the blur handler. There's some other issue here. Your answer doesn't solve any issue.

Comment: OP says trying `$("input[id='primaryEmail.Revisit']").val()` and `$("input[id='primaryEmail.Revisit']").attr("value")` both do not. But it actually works that is what I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Right. But it doesn't solve any issue. More information is needed. "Works for me" answer are [not answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid).

Comment: That atleast highligts OP to look into somewhere else in the code.

Comment: And that should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: [`function getEmailVal() {
   var emailValue = $('#primaryEmail\\.Revisit').val();
   alert(emailValue);
   return emailValue; 
  }
    
    $("#login").click(function() {
   var emailValue = getEmailVal();
   rebakeCookies();
  });`]

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor - What do you see in `alert(emailValue)`?

Comment: I see nothing. The alert is blank.

Comment: Can you try this `alert($("input[id='primaryEmail.Revisit']").val())` in a console and see what it gives?